# Python: how to print 1 thing from a list

Tags: python

i have just started to learn python and I am stuck on how to only print 1 thing from a list(eg. just the cake) and not the whole list.

```
data = ["Shopping List:\nEggs\nBread\nMilk\nChicken", "Cake", "Feed Dog"]
```

Thanks

Comment: `print data[1]`

Comment: And in python 3 `print(data[0])`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you could have found out the solution by spending some time with google.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ["Shopping List:\nEggs\nBread\nMilk\nChicken", "Cake", "Feed Dog"]
print(data[0])
```

This will print the first item of the list. Idem for item 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the element's index/position in the list to access the respective element of the list, by using the [] operator. Try:

```
print(data[1])
```

This is stating you would like the 1st element; remember it's zero based indexing. So what you might call the 'first' element in conversation, is actually the zeroth.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = ["Shopping List:\nEggs\nBread\nMilk\nChicken", "Cake", "Feed Dog"]
```

This is the array `data`. This means that:

- At `data[0]`, there is "Shopping List:\nEggs\nBread\nMilk\nChicken".
- At `data[1]`, there is "Cake"
- At `data[2]`, there is "Feed Dog"

> I am stuck on how to only print 1 thing from a list

If you want to print only one thing from this list, you have to use its index in the `print()` statement. In python 3, the following statement is used:

```
print (data[1]) # 1 is just an example here. You can use 0 or 2
```

In python 2, the following statement is used:

```
print data[1] # 1 is just an example here You can use 0 or 2
```

In both cases, "Cake" is output.

Answer (score 1):

well
this is easy
all u have to do is pass the index value of the list/array u want to print and it will print u the expected value

```
arr[0...n-1]
```

note the array/list value starts from 0 to n-1 elements
in ur case list value varies from 0...2

```
print(data[0])==>will print "Shopping List:\nEggs\nBread\nMilk\nChicken".
print(data[1])==>will print "Cake"
print(data[2])==>will print "Feed Dog"
```